# Check array and put in another array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array

```
$arr =('1-1.jpg','1-2.jpg','11-3.jpg', '1-4.jpg', '3-5.jpg', '41-5.jpg','1-3.jpg','4-5.jpg','14-5.jpg','54-5.jpg','64-5.jpg','14-5.jpg', '1-5.jpg');
```

How can I make new array to look like this :

```
$newarray=('1-1.jpg','1-2.jpg','1-3.jpg', '1-4.jpg', '1-5.jpg');
```

Comment: What is the rule for creating this new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PHP array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a callback that says "the string starts with `1-`" then sort the result.

```
$new = array_filter( $arr, function( $el) { 
    return substr( $el, 0, 2) == '1-'; 
});
sort( $new);
```

Comment: Can you write it, because i think it only works on exit od string :*

Comment: @Miomir - I've updated Ray's answer with an example. You can see it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/RldPHF).

Comment: Works like a charms, txanks mates :)

Comment: I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION